# How to give a navigation to nested child gridview inside a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, nested, repeater

I need your help, I have a nested repeater parent (`Repeater1`) and child gridview (`gvNewChild`). Parent repeater is calling the record Id (`FId`) from parent table and child gridview is getting record Id (`FId`) on `OnItemDataBound` of parent repeater from child table, so both the parent and child table are different but linked with `FId` which is the same record Id number in both the table.

Now I am able to retrieve the data in both outer repeater and child gridview from both the table using their `FId` respectively. But I am wondering if there is a possibilities to give navigation in the child gridview instead of showing all the record at a time, so actually I want my child repeater to show only one record and to access other record I want to use next and previous navigation. Please guide me, below is the code:

```aspx
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="OnItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <u><b>
                <asp:Label ID="Label7" class="HeadMasterTextBox" Width="" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NTitle") %>'></asp:Label>
            </b></u>
            <asp:Label ID="lblDetails" class="HeadMasterTextBox" Width="" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NDetails") %>'></asp:Label>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Style="display: block;">
                GridView ID="gvNewChild" runat="server" DataKeyNames="FId" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                               CssClass="tableWall" HeaderStyle-BorderColor="#ffffff" GridLines="None" Visible="true"
                                               AllowPaging="true"  PageSize="1" OnPageIndexChanging="gvNewChild_PageIndexChanging" >
                                               <Columns>
                                                   <asp:TemplateField>
                                                       <ItemTemplate>
                                                           <table border="0" width="100%" align="center" class="">
                                                               <tr>
                                                                   <td align="center" colspan="2">

                                                                     <!--  <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imgData" class="imgwall" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageName") %>'
                                                                           CommandName='<%# Eval("FId") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ImageName") %>' />
                                                                           -->

                                                                           <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("BData")) %>'
                                                    Height="180px" Width="200px" />

                                                    <br />
                                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Visible="true" Text='<%# Eval("ImageName") %>'></asp:Label>

                                                                   </td>
                                                               </tr>
                                                               <tr>
                                                                   <td style="vertical-align: top;" align="center">
                                                                       <asp:Label ID="lblFId" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("FId") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                                       <asp:TextBox ID="txt_GFId" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Visible="true" Text='<%# Eval("FId") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                                                       <br />
                                                                       <asp:LinkButton Text="" ID="lnkFIdCount" class="tableAdminTextBox" CommandArgument='<%#  Eval("FId") %>'
                                                                           runat="server" CommandName="Select" />
                                                                   </td>
                                                               </tr>
                                                           </table>

                                                       </ItemTemplate>
                                                   </asp:TemplateField>
                                               </Columns>
                                               <RowStyle BackColor="#ffffff" ForeColor="#333333" />
                                           </asp:GridView>
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hfFId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("FId") %>' />
                                    </asp:Panel>
                               </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
```

Below is the source:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    Repeater1.DataSource = GetData("select *from News order by (Id) desc");
    Repeater1.DataBind();
}

private static DataTable GetData(string query)
{
    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BHCONNECTION"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{ 
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        string FId = (e.Item.FindControl("hfFId") as HiddenField).Value;
        Repeater rptOrders = e.Item.FindControl("rptOrders") as Repeater;
        rptOrders.DataSource = GetData(string.Format("select * from NewsPic where FId='{0}'", FId));
        rptOrders.DataBind();
    }
}


 protected void gvNewChild_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    { 
        GridView gvNewChild = (sender as GridView);
        gvNewChild.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        gvNewChild.DataBind();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at quick example:

**HTML-Markup:**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:Label ID="lblFID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FID") %>'></asp:Label>
        <!-- Your other controls -->
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="1"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>

               <asp:Label ID="lblFID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FID") %>'></asp:Label>
               <!-- Your other controls -->

                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" CssClass="pagination-ys" />
        </asp:GridView>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Code-Behind:**

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
             e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        string FId = (e.Item.FindControl("FID") as Label).Text;
        GridView GridView1 = e.Item.FindControl("GridView1") as GridView;

        // select data from parent Table
        GridView1.DataSource = 
                GetData(string.Format("select * from ParentTable where FId='{0}'", FId));
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    // get repeater item where clicked
    RepeaterItem item = ((GridView)sender).Parent as RepeaterItem;
    string FId = ((Label)Repeater1.Items[item.ItemIndex].FindControl("FID")).Text;

    // get gridview from Repeater
    GridView GridView1 = (sender as GridView);
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

    // select data from child table
    GridView1.DataSource = 
            GetData(string.Format("select * from ChildTable where FId='{0}'", FId));
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

**Paging Style:**

```
.pagination-ys {
    //display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 20px 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.pagination-ys table > tbody > tr > td {
    display: inline;
}

.pagination-ys table > tbody > tr > td > a,
.pagination-ys table > tbody > tr > td > span {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #dd4814;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    margin-left: -1px;
}

.pagination-ys table > tbody > tr > td > span {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-decoration: none;    
    margin-left: -1px;
    z-index: 2;
    color: #aea79f;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-color: #dddddd;
    cursor: default;
}

.pagination-ys table > tbody > tr > td:first-child > a,
.pagination-ys table > tbody > tr > td:first-child > span {
    margin-left: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
}

.pagination-ys table > tbody > tr > td:last-child > a,
.pagination-ys table > tbody > tr > td:last-child > span {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

.pagination-ys table > tbody > tr > td > a:hover,
.pagination-ys table > tbody > tr > td > span:hover,
.pagination-ys table > tbody > tr > td > a:focus,
.pagination-ys table > tbody > tr > td > span:focus {
    color: #97310e;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border-color: #dddddd;
}
```

Comment: @ Asif, It works like a charm!!! Thanks a ton life saver. But can I also have a next and previous navigation instead of page number?

Comment: You can follow this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pagertemplate.aspx

Comment: @ Asif sorry to bother you, but I actually checked now and it is showing some record and not showing some record (Child Record - Gridview). so it is in this way, It is skipping after every record, for example record 1 is showing and record 2 is not showing but record 3 is showing and record 4 is not showing and so on... could you give me this last help please been trying long.

Comment: @ Asif I figured it out here : if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)

Comment: so what happened to this `if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)`. Is it solved?